# How to prove the independence of difference in relational algebra?

Tags: relational-structures

The five basic operator select, project, cartesian product, union and difference in relational algebra are independent of each other. But how to prove the independence of difference in relational algebra?

Comment: Select, project, cartesian products, and unions are all monotone, as is composition. But difference is antitone in one argument, so it obviously can't be expressed as a composition of monotone functions.